# Automatically Trigger write fields from polygon to point when adding point

Tags: polygon, point, sql, trigger

When editing, I would like to create an SQL trigger that will write fields from my parcels layer to a point layer that the end user is editing.

Essentially, when a point is placed on a parcel, that point will automatically have all of the address information written to the point's attribute table from the parcel attribute table based off spatial location.

Any ideas?

Comment: What data type are you editing?

Comment: We are just adding points to a GIS web map.